# Django: Fields as list element in models

Tags: django, django-models

Actually I don't know if its possible but this is a rough example of what do I want

its like,

```py
class ImAModel(models.Model):
   field_of_list_of_questions = (models.BooleanField(), models.BooleanField(), models.BooleanField())
```

I need this beacuse I will have a model that have a vary field. And also there may be a lot of fields in it. Then I want to call them like this `val = model.field_of_lists_of_questions[1]`

It'll be very enjoying if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can however define three fields, and a property to group these:

```
class ImAModel(models.Model):
    question1 = models.BooleanField()
    question2 = models.BooleanField()
    question3 = models.BooleanField()

    @property
    def list_of_questions(self):
        return (self.question1, self.question2, self.question3)

    @list_of_questions.setter
    def list_of_questions(self, value):
        self.question1, self.question2, self.question3 = value
```